# How to get value from h:outputText which is inside p:repeat element

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to get values from the outputText component which is inside the repeat component:

```html
<p:dataTable>
...
<p:column sortBy="#{row.trainnumber}" style="text-align: right; text-overflow: ellipsis; width: 80px" exportFunction="#{columnExporter.export}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Zugnr." title="Zugnummer" />
    </f:facet>

    <p:repeat var="item" value="#{row.values}" varStatus="aendStatus">
        <h:outputText  value="#{item.trainnumber}" />
        <h:outputText value="&lt;br /&gt;" escape="false" rendered="#{!someValue.last}" />
    </p:repeat>
</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

For this, I'm using `exportFunction`. Below is an example code:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.component.ValueHolder;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.primefaces.component.api.UIColumn;
import org.primefaces.component.repeat.UIRepeat;
import org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils;

@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class ColumnExporter {

    public String export(final UIColumn column) {
        String value = StringUtils.EMPTY;
        for (final UIComponent child : column.getChildren())
            value += buildValue(child);
        return value;
    }

    private String buildValue(final UIComponent uiComponent) {
        if (uiComponent.isRendered()) {
            if (uiComponent instanceof ValueHolder) {
                return ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), uiComponent);
            } else if (uiComponent instanceof UIRepeat) {
                UIRepeat repeat = (UIRepeat) uiComponent;
                return buildRepeatValue(repeat);
            } else if (uiComponent.getChildCount() > 0) {
                String value = "";
                for (UIComponent child : uiComponent.getChildren()) {
                    value += buildValue(child);
                }
                return value;
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    private String buildRepeatValue(UIRepeat repeat) {
        String value = "";
        String variableName = repeat.getVar();
        String statusName = repeat.getVarStatus();
        List<?> values = (List) repeat.getValueExpression("value")
                .getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext());
        for (Object valueObj : values) {
            for (UIComponent child : repeat.getChildren()) {
                String childValue = buildValue(child);
                if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(childValue)) {
                    value += childValue + "\n";
                }
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

But I always get the NULL value despite the fact that this value is correctly displayed in the table.
Does anyone know how to properly retrieve this value from the outputText element?

Comment: Tried *not** using a p:datatable and a ui:repeat? Does it work then?

Comment: Works without ui:repeat - I can get value from outputText

Comment: **With** ui:repeat (instead of p:repeat)

Comment: It does not change anything. I understand that the problem is that in ui:repeat component there really only exists one outputText element for many values. How do you get these values if you do not find in this item?